# Reverse sort of matrix columns

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Say, if I do this for some matrix `A`:

```
[sorted,inds] = sort(A,1,'descend')
```

How do I do a reverse sort of this matrix?

I need something like this:
http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/08/21/reversal-of-a-sort/#7

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Say `A = [8 4 6 8;3 2 5 6;9 3 4 5]`. What should the output be?

Comment: The same matrix. Please, see the link provided - there is an example for simple 1D case

Comment: The same matrix? Do nothing then? Please be more explicit. What output do you want?

Comment: After I sorted the matrix, I need to perform some operations that do depend on the sorted result. These operations modify element values. Therefore, after operations are done I need all elements of the matrix in the initial order

Comment: You need the inverse permutation. For the list `inds` you need `inverse_inds(inds)=1:length(inds)`. [Source](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/81070-how-to-find-the-reverse-of-a-permutation-vector).

Comment: @AndrasDeak yes, it works pefectly for 1D case. I'm asking about 2D case. I was not able to extend this result to 2D case.

Comment: @sof_dff oh... nver saw this behaviour in Matlab before. Weird indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = [8 4 6 8;3 2 5 6;9 3 4 5];
[sorted,inds] = sort(A,1,'descend')

B = NaN(size(A));
B(bsxfun(@plus, inds, 0:size(A,1):numel(A)-1)) = sorted;
```

gives `B` equal to `A`.

The trick is that `inds` should be interpreted as column indices. You need to convert to linear indices, which is easily done with `bsxfun`.

Comment: Thanks! That what I needed

Comment: @sof_dff Glad it worked. It took me some time to understand what you wanted!